# Can I *actually* lock my computer, so that the only thing I can do is type my password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, password-protection, lock, ease-of-access

I make frequent use of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which will lock my computer and prompt me to enter my password to unlock it. This is to prevent other (mischevious) people from doing anything while I am away.

However, it is still possible to mess with the computer in this locked state. One can access the Ease of Access Center from the lock screen, which looks like this:

*(Click image to enlarge)*

[image]

They can then turn on Narrator (read everything), Magnifier (magnify the area around your cursor), High Contrast (make the colors of the UI strange), On-Screen Keyboard (open up an annoying keyboard in a window), Sticky Keys (ctrl, alt, win, etc. "stick" so you can press one at a time), and Filter Keys (ignore keys pressed multiple times in a row).

These settings are quite annoying by themselves, and activating all of them at once is even more so.

Is there any way to completely lock the computer, so that the only possible action is to enter a password?

Comment: I'm with @Keltari in that your question seems to be asking how you can disable Ease of Access.  I mean, you aren't directly asking that, but you are *indirectly* asking it.  If you were to disable Ease of Access, would that solve your problem?

Comment: @BonGart Yes, I have realized that is true. I don't have enough rep to closevote my question yet, but you can.

Comment: That's Ok.  You might have been looking for an alternative to disabling that function.